How to generate a readable report from the xml output of Cppcheck/Cppcheclipse?
I am using Eclipse CDT for embedded development. I installed Cppcheck and the Eclipse plugin cppcheclipse for static analysis. When I run cppcheck in the IDE it generates xml data in the console.
I tried copying the data and created an xml file from it but it is still unreadable. There should be a way to have the IDE/cppcheck generate a human readable report so I can see what are all the errors and warings.
I tried Googling a solution, but the only one I found requires me to create a file for the command line cppcheck tool and requires me to download LibreOffice to do some conversion.
I do not want to have to run external command line tools and download programs I am not going to use. This seems like it should be an easy check box setting in Eclipse/cppcheck/cppcheclipse or I add some parameters to the list of command line arguments that get run when I invoke cppcheck.
I have tried adding to the advancewd settings but that also did not work.
In addition, where in Eclipse can I see the command line arguments that cppcheck uses when run from Eclipse? I cannot find it under workspace->preferences->cppcheclipse and project->properties->cppcheclipse.
Last question, I have tried rerunning cppcheck/cppcheclipse but it does not generate output anymore. It did it the first time, but no output since then.
Here is an example of the output:
<error id="bufferAccessOutOfBounds" severity="error" msg="Buffer is accessed out of bounds: buf" verbose="Buffer is accessed out of bounds: buf" cwe="788"/>
        <error id="objectIndex" severity="error" msg="The address of variable &apos;&apos; is accessed at non-zero index." verbose="The address of variable &apos;&apos; is accessed at non-zero index." cwe="758"/>
        <error id="argumentSize" severity="warning" msg="Buffer &apos;buffer&apos; is too small, the function &apos;function&apos; expects a bigger buffer in 2nd argument" verbose="Buffer &apos;buffer&apos; is too small, the function &apos;function&apos; expects a bigger buffer in 2nd argument" cwe="398">
            <symbol>function</symbol>
        </error>


It's documented here: https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.html#html-report Alternatively, you can write an XSLT that converts the XML report to HTML.

Thanks @howlger, I Googled cppcheck manual and it never came up in Google that is why I missed it. Do you know where inEclipse I can add those command-line arguments so that when I run cppcheck in Eclipse it runs those arguments to generate the HTML report?

You might add it as a so-called external tool: Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations...
